# Drawing hatch filled rectangles with differing angles in python

Tags: python, drawing

I'm trying to draw a 2D rectangular plate in python. This plate will be split into a variable number of sections, each of these sections will be filled with a hatched pattern. This hatched pattern will have a specified angle. As an example for a rectangle with 5 sections and an array of its section hatch orientation (in degrees) being [0, 45, 0, -45, 0] is shown below. It will need to be able to display any orientation, not just the usual 90, 45, 0, i.e. 33, 74.5 etc.

[image]

Any idea how I could do this? Essentially I just want to show the orientation in each section, any other methods of expressing the same results would be much appreciated e.g. a single line instead of hatched.

Edit (after question was answered):
Edited script provided by Greg is shown below.

```
from numpy import cos, sin
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

angles = [0,10,20,30,40,50]

numberOfSections = len(angles)

def plot_hatches(ax, angle, offset=.1):
    angle_radians = np.radians(angle)
    x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
    for c in np.arange(-2, 2, offset):
        yprime = cos(angle_radians) * c - sin(angle_radians) * x
        xprime = sin(angle_radians) * c + cos(angle_radians) * x
        ax.plot(xprime, yprime, color="b", linewidth=2)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
    return ax

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=numberOfSections, figsize=(16,(16/numberOfSections)), sharex=True, sharey=True)

for i in range(len(axes.flat)):
    plot_hatches(axes.flat[i], angles[i])

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, wspace=0)  
plt.show()
```

Produces an figure shown below.
[image]
But on inspection the angles do not match the input angles.

Answer (score 4):

I have a basic idea although I suspect you will need to do quite a bit more depending how flexible you want the result to be.

```
from numpy import cos, sin
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_hatches(ax, angle, offset=.1):
    angle_radians = np.radians(angle)
    x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 10)
    for c in np.arange(-2, 2, offset):
        yprime = cos(angle_radians) * c + sin(angle_radians) * x
        xprime = sin(angle_radians) * c - cos(angle_radians) * x
        ax.plot(xprime, yprime, color="k")
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
    return ax


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4, figsize=(8,8), sharex=True, sharey=True)

for i in range(len(axes.flat)):
    plot_hatches(axes.flat[i], np.random.uniform(0, 90))

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, wspace=0)
```

There is two things parts here: firstly a function `plot_hatches` which draws hatches over the unit square on the axes `ax`. This is done by taking a single line `x, y=c` and rotating it using [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to get a `xprime` and `yprime` which are the coordinates of lines at an angle to the x axis with offset `c`. Iterating over several values of `c` covers the unit square, the lines can be made denser by making the `offset` argument smaller.

Secondly we need a method to draw the axes next to each other. This I have done using `subplots`. This returns `fig, axes` the `axes` is an array of axes instances, so we iteratate through them passing them into the function to plot hatches and give it a random angle each time.

[image]

**EDIT** 
I have changed the plot_hatches code to rotate in an anticlockwise manner (it was clockwise before this edit). This will now produce exactly the image given in the question with the array `[0, -45, 0, 45, 0]`:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I have a few questions if you don't mind. So this produces random angle hatches now, how could I get it to produce just a 1X4 grid using an array specified e.g. [0,63,86,-11]? So essentially I want to be able to specify the angles. Thanks once again for your help!

Comment: In the for loop I call `plot_hatches`, it takes two arguments: the first is the axes to plot over and the second the angle. To make it 1x4 you need to change the number of rows and columns in `plt.subplots` (this is where the axes are creates). Then just run the for loop but instead of giving a random angle plug in your angle from the list. I advise you just save this as a script and hack around. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: Greg, I've changed it now so I can specify my own array of angles, but the angles don't seem to be correct. I've edited the original question  to show you.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I think the angles are correct as long as each sub-plot remains square, but I'm most likely to use rectangular sections. How could this be achieved?